# Is there any possible ways to add significant stars and brackets besides Complexheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

I have created the oncoprint by `Complexheatmap` in R like this:
[oncoprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHHuA.png)

I'm wondering is it possible to use ggplot or other package to add significant stars like this:

[significant stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3nYv.png)

besides the oncoprint?

So I did

```
column_title = "OncoPrint "
heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "Alternations", at = c("UP", "AMP", "MUT"), 
                            labels = c("Over Expression", "Amplification", "Mutation"))
oncoPrint(df1,
          alter_fun = alter_fun, col = col, 
          column_title = column_title, heatmap_legend_param = heatmap_legend_param, 
          right_annotation  = NULL, top_annotation = NULL, row_names_side = "left",
          show_pct = FALSE)
```

And the output is:

[image]

However, I want to add significant stars like this
[image]

or this:

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible?

I have tried to use complexheatmap with ggplot2, but it seems that they are unable to use together.